# Use Python Selenium to get span text

Tags: python, selenium

This should be easy, but I can't get it to work. I'm running a little demo using the Google homepage as a test.

Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.google.com") # Load page

time.sleep(0.2)

#top nav elements
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'gbts')]") 

for e in elems:
    print e.get_attribute('text')

browser.close()
```

It returns:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

So I think it's grabbing the right elements, but perhaps not the right attribute? Not sure. I also tried to print e.text() but that spit out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 14, in <module>
    print e.text()
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Any thoughts?

**Edit - Possible Solution? **

```
e.get_attribute('innerHTML') seems to work.
```

Comment: I was having the same issue and your *Edit-Possible Solution* works for me too.
`e.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "gbts"]'):
    print elem.text
```

---

`text` is a property of the `WebElement` class, thus it is not callable.

```
class WebElement(object):
    """Represents an HTML element.       
    ...
    ...

    @property
    def text(self):
        """Gets the text of the element."""
        return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
```

---

You have two alternatives to get the third match:

```
#  1. Modify your xpath expression
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "gbts"])[3]')[0].text

#  2. Access it by list index
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "gbts"])')[2].text
```

Comment: Got to it first... yup, `text` is an attribute of a webelement object, not a method.

Comment: Cool. Other question, how do I grab only the 3rd span?

Comment: @doremi -- as `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "gbts"]')` returns a list you can just access it by index...

Answer (score 21):

YES ! Solution was found (I`am using Python)
For instanc: webelement is a p tag

```
webelement.text()
```

from real situation, stacktrace:

print page_box_block.text() 
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

it expect to be a html in stdout, but not !

sometimes could be a strange string "unicode object is not callable" or some type error
solution is very easy:

```
print element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

In java get_attribute("innerHTML") and text() are about to "same",  if you need plain text from element
In Python 2.7 for now text() sometimes fails.

Comment: In Python 2.7 for now text() sometimes fails. Thanks for your notice

Comment: In Python 2.7 for now text() sometimes fails. saved my life +1

Comment: Thanks for the .get_attribute("innerHTML"). It was what I was looking for!

Comment: I ran into a situation where `webelement.text` was returning empty strings in a part of the page that contained a span element with no class name. However,  `element.get_attribute("innerHTML")` worked well in those situations. `Python 3.7 | Selenium 3.141.0`