# Unable to extract table data using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]
The issue i have is that the print statement at the end returns NONE . i want to store the values at every 6 spot in each row which is fine and working correctly .
BUT the print(self.mystr) at the end doesn't give me a value .

please help/ advise.

i log in to this website and use it . trying to automate a few things.

```
def click_single_tractor(self): #dynamically clicks tractor
    sleep(2)
    basecss = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXMainTable > tbody > tr'
    cssbase = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXHeadersRow > td'

    table_rows = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(basecss)
    table_data = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(cssbase)

    for index, tr in enumerate(table_rows,1):
        iteratingSelObj = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( basecss, str(index)))
        print('table row:',int(index))

        for indx, td in enumerate(table_data,1):
            iterate_td = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( cssbase, str(indx)))
            print('table data:',int(indx))
            if indx == 6:
                #get value of element
                # add to string ? to get value
                

                self.mystr.append(td.get_attribute('text'))


    print(self.mystr)
```

im displaying the rows and table data on purpose as a self check and it returns the right amount of data
7 rows, 10 table datas per row.

the web table is kind of dynamic because occasionally gets an item added to it which is why im reading the info dynamically that way i dont have to mess with the code if we add an item.

result:

**table row: 1**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 2**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 3**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 4**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 5**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 6**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**table row: 7**

table data: 1
table data: 2
table data: 3
table data: 4
table data: 5
table data: 6
table data: 7
table data: 8
table data: 9
table data: 10

**[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]**

Comment: your question is not complete, post also the HTML snippet

Comment: self.mystr.append(td.text) didnt work for me. is there any other way i can get that value?

Answer (score 0):

`text` is not an attribute of an Selenium Web Element. We use get_attribute to get attributes of a web element such as its class, id, etc. Basically the stuff you see within the `<div id=..., class=.., whatever=... >`, the words with the `=` sign are called properties.

To get the text of a Selenium WebElement simply use `td.text`, where `td` is a Selenium Web Element.

A similar question and answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590341/use-python-selenium-to-get-span-text).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! This was what i tried before among a few other things that either didnt run or didnt give me the answer i wanted. this prints out the first row table data only , is it possible this information is protected?

Comment: the first row is not the dynamic info . its just the titles for the table data

Comment: ['Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico']

Comment: each of those values is the 6th table data info for each row but it should be dynamic

Comment: self.mystr.append(td.text)      gives that result