# How to get the inner text from an <a> tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, innerhtml, getattribute

I want to select the Remember Sports part of this line

```
<a href="https://ww.allmusic.com/artist/remember-sports-mn0003731048">Remember Sports</a>
```

I can get the href but how do I get the actual text?

This is what I tried, when I tried to pass another argument into get_attribute or leave it blank then it doesn't work.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('c:\\Users\\16308\\Documents\\VSCPython\chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.allmusic.com/album/sunchokes-mw0003322304'
browser.get(url)
stages = browser.find_element_by_class_name('album-artist')
artist_link = stages.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
artist_link_text = stages.find_element_by_css_selector('a')
browser.get(artist_link)
print(artist_link_text)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`, if it was an input you could also use 'value' instead of innerHTML.

EDIT:

There is another very similar question: [Use Python Selenium to get span text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590341/use-python-selenium-to-get-span-text)

Answer (score 0):

Select your element using xpath or css then use get text method to get the text inside:

```
Text=stages.find_element_by_css_selector('a').text
```

Or

```
text=driver.findElement(By.className("Class Locator").getText( );
```

Answer (score 0):

The text ***Remember Sports*** is within the following element:

```
<h2 class="album-artist">
    <span>
        <a href="https://www.allmusic.com/artist/remember-sports-mn0003731048">Remember Sports</a>            
    </span>
</h2>
```

---

### Solution

To extract the text you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.album-artist a[href^='https://www.allmusic.com/artist']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='album-artist']//a[@href='https://www.allmusic.com/artist/remember-sports-mn0003731048']").text)
  ```